# How come 2 ^ 3 = 1 in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.9

Shouldn't it be 8?

The same thing goes with 3 ^ 2. I also got 1.

This is confusing...
[image]

Comment: Please read the language specification before guessing what its operators do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `^` is a bitwise XOR operator. I believe what you're looking for is the exponent operator, `**`. An example would be `2**3` which outputs `8`, like I believe you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The ^ operator does a bitwise XOR operation. In python to do power calculation use `pow()` function:

```
pow(3,2)
```

Or use `**`

```
3**2
```